# Spring MVC Controllers mapping not registered

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm making some tests with spring mvc this days and I have one problem. For a basic application to test with I choose this tutorial:
http://loianegroner.com/2010/09/extjs-spring-mvc-3-and-hibernate-3-5-crud-datagrid-example/
I've downloaded the example and everything works as expected. The problem is when I try to add another Controller. It seems that file I'm adding is not scanned.

My web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.loiane" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- misc -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configures Hibernate - Database Config -->
<import resource="db-config.xml" />
```

as you can see there are context:component-scan and mvc:annotation-driven tags which should tell spring to scan all the classes in com.lione package for @Controller annotation. But when I try to add my own controller to this application it seems it's not processed. Only first controller is mapped.

Here is my controller code

```
    package com.loiane.web;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld.action")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("helloWorld");
        mav.addObject("message", "Hello World!");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

After running this in eclipse console log I've got

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contact/delete.action] onto handler 'contactController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contact/create.action] onto handler 'contactController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contact/update.action] onto handler 'contactController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contact/view.action] onto handler 'contactController'
```

but /helloWorld.action is missing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything looks fine. Perhaps for some reason your controller is not added to the webapp you run.

Comment: somehow I got it mapped. I don't know where the problem was but after creating new project and import all the files again it start working.

Comment: you might want to close off this question to prevent others from stumbling onto it by mistake

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is a good idea to be more specific with your path when using `<context:component-scan base-package="package-name" />`
So  you should be doing `<context:component-scan base-package="com.loiane.web" />`